# I live, yet I die every day

Tags: riddle, wordplay

*Am I a plague, a curse, a sin?*
   *I don't even know where I begin.*

*Some parts of me love, some parts of me hate.*
   *But I'm pretty sure Mother doesn't think I am great.*

*Viewed as a virus, they say I will never die out.*
   *Although lately I am filled with much doubt.*

*What am I?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you (perhaps a rather bleak take on)

> people/humanity?

Because:

Am I a plague, a curse, a sin?

> This could be a reference to the inherent evil nature of some people.

I don't even know where I begin.

> Unless I missed something, we aren't 100% sure where or how (human) life started.

Some parts of me love, some parts of me hate.

> Some people are nice/loving, some people are evil/hateful.

But I'm pretty sure Mother doesn't think I am great.

> Not sure on this one, perhaps "Mother" as in mother earth, and "doesn't think I am great" could be a reference to pollution and/or the use of natural resources?

Viewed as a virus, they say I will never die out.
Although lately I am filled with much doubt.

> And here's where I become really unsure, but perhaps this could mean some people say it's too late to reverse humanity's negative effects on the earth..?  Eh.

Oh, and for the title:

> Lots of people currently living, and every day people die.

Comment: I was going for Humanity, so I'll give you that, but not exactly what I was going for on each line. Some people view humanity as a virus on Earth, that we aren't needed for it to continue, but we often feel invincible. However lately people seem to be filled with doubt as to how long people will live with the Earth dying.